# Impala / Hive - Extract text from comma delimited string where each separation doesnt match a pattern

Tags: sql, regex, hive, impala

is there a way in hive or impala to extract a string from a delimited string but only where the string i want doesnt match one or multiple patterns?

For instance, i have a field with IPs (the number varies depending on network adapters):

```
169.254.182.175,192.168.0.1,10.199.44.111
```

I would like to extract the IP that doesnt start with 169.254. (there could be many of these) and doesnt equal 192.168.0.1

The IPs can be in any order as well.

I tried doing substr with nested cases but due the unknown number of ips in the string it didnt work out.

Could this be accomplished with regex_extract or something similar?

Thanks,

Comment: as impala has no split function, you should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 0):

You may use `regexp_replace` with capturing group for patterns that you *do not* want to keep and specify only groups of interest in the replacement string.

See example below in Impala (impalad version 3.4.0):

> ```
> select
>   addr_list,
>   /*Concat is used just for visualization*/
>   rtrim(ltrim(regexp_replace(addr_list,concat(
>     /*Group of 169.254.*.* that should be excluded*/
>     '(169\\.254\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})', '|',
>     /*Another group for 192.168.0.1*/
>     '(192\.168\.0\.1)', '|',
>     /*And the group that we need to keep*/
>     '(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})'
>     
>     /*So keep the third group in the output.
>       Other groups will be replaced with empty string*/
>   ), '\\3'), ','), ',') as ip_whitelist
> from(values
>  ('169.254.182.175,192.168.0.1,169.254.2.12,10.199.44.111,169.254.0.2' as addr_list),
>  ('10.58.3.142,169.254.2.12'),
>  ('192.168.0.1,192.100.0.2,154.16.171.3')
> ) as t
> ```
>
> | addr_list | ip_whitelist |
> | --- | --- |
> | 169.254.182.175,192.168.0.1,169.254.2.12,10.199.44.111,169.254.0.2 | 10.199.44.111 |
> | 10.58.3.142,169.254.2.12 | 10.58.3.142 |
> | 192.168.0.1,192.100.0.2,154.16.171.3 | 192.100.0.2,154.16.171.3 |

`regexp_extract` works differently for unknown reason, because the same regex with 3 as return group doesn't return anything at all for case 1 and 3.

> ```
> select
>   t.addr_list,
>   rtrim(ltrim(regexp_replace(addr_list, r.regex, '\\3'), ','), ',') as ip_whitelist,
>   regexp_extract(addr_list, r.regex, 3) as ip_wl_extract
> from(values
>   ('169.254.182.175,192.168.0.1,169.254.2.12,10.199.44.111,169.254.0.2' as addr_list),
>   ('10.58.3.142,169.254.2.12'),
>   ('192.168.0.1,192.100.0.2,154.16.171.3')
> ) as t
>   cross join (
>     select concat(
>       '(169\\.254\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})', '|',
>       '(192\.168\.0\.1)', '|',
>       '(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})'
>     ) as regex
>   ) as r
> ```
>
> | addr_list | ip_whitelist | ip_wl_extract |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 169.254.182.175,192.168.0.1,169.254.2.12,10.199.44.111,169.254.0.2 | 10.199.44.111 |  |
> | 10.58.3.142,169.254.2.12 | 10.58.3.142 | 10.58.3.142 |
> | 192.168.0.1,192.100.0.2,154.16.171.3 | 192.100.0.2,154.16.171.3 |  |

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining both of them. I used the regex_replace as you suggested and just removed any of the strings that match the 169. nd 254. and i was always left with the string i wanted no matter where it was:

rtrim(ltrim(regexp_replace(d.ipaddress,'(169\\.254\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})|(192\.168\.0\.1)|(,)', ''))) as RegIP

Comment: @Whitts Yes, you are right. There's to need to capture a group we do want, but just replace other text. Thank you